# How to make a line break in textinput after insert a image component inside of it? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im new in react-native and im doing a bloc note, the problem now is that i want to allow the user put images with the note, something like this:

[image: R]

my structure for this for now is this:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <View style = {this.styles.container}> 
                <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_title} placeholder = "Title" multiline = {true} maxLength = {80} value = {this.state.title} onChangeText = {title => this.setState({title: title})}></TextInput>
                <View style = {this.styles.textinput_container}>
                    <TextInput  style = {this.styles.textinput} multiline = {true} onChangeText = {content => this.setState({content: content})}><Text>{this.state.content}{"\n"}</Text>
                    <Text>{this.state.img}</Text>
                    </TextInput>
                    <Button title = "Add image" onPress = {this.add_Image}></Button>
                    <Button title = "Save Changes" onPress = {this.save_Changes}></Button>
                </View>
            </View>
      }

 add_Image = () => {
    this.setState({content: this.state.content + "\n\n\n"});
    const img = <Image source = {require("../img/ny.png")} style = {{width: 100, height: 100}}></Image>
    this.setState({img:img});
}
```

for now im just using a button to add the image to see if it works, but i get this:

[image]

as you can see, the pointer (the blue line) is still there and doesnt does a line break, maybe is the way that im using to do this, but like i said, im new and for now i dont know another way to do this, so if anyone can help me, really will appreciate :)

Comment: you need to learn ```Flex```.  https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: hi, everybody told me about flex, but i really dont know how to implement it, theres no examples for what im trying to do, not even close, so if you can give me an orientation or steps something to start

Comment: Why you are insert image inside textinput?? You can add image above textinput and write comment in textinput??

Comment: No, I'm making a bloc note, so i want to allow the user put a img with his note and the continue to write below if it

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by some modifications to the style:

E.G:

```
<Text style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: '25%' }}>{this.state.img}</Text>
```

Where,

1. marginTop: Gona gives you the proportion of the space you want to leave on top.
2. flex: Set it on 1 it's going to put it on its on space.